# Split traffic between 2 ClusterIP k8s services using a virtual service

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have two Pods running in Kubernetes exposed by ClusterIP services, let's say `nginx-1` and `nginx-2`. I want to create a virtual service `nginx-split`, which route 75% of the traffic to `nginx-1` and 25% of the traffic to `nginx-2`. What I understood from the documentation is that I should create a VirtualService definition file:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  hosts:
  - nginx-split
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx-1
      weight: 75
    - destination:
        host: nginx-2
      weight: 25
```

VirtualService definition is not enough, maybe I should also create a ServiceEntry. The problem is that I don't know how to define a Service Entry for `nginx-split` since it is just virtual and should not be resolved to (one) IP address.

Answer (score 0):

[TRAFFIC SPLITTING:How it works](https://www.istioworkshop.io/09-traffic-management/03-traffic-splitting/)
[image]

The traffic splitting is handled by [two Istio Objects:](https://www.istioworkshop.io/09-traffic-management/03-traffic-splitting/#how-it-works)

- [VirtualService](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) - defines a set of traffic routing rules to apply when a host is addressed.
- [DestinationRule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/) - defines policies that apply to traffic intended for a service after routing has occurred.

We create a `VirtualService` that list the different variation with their the `weight`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  hosts:
    - service-a
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: service-a
            subset: v1
          weight: 80
        - destination:
            host: service-a
            subset: v2
          weight: 20
```

Then the `DestinationRule` is responsible for defining the destination of the traffic and the traffic policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: property-business-service
spec:
  host: property-business-service
  subsets:
    - name: v1
      labels:
        version: "1.0"
    - name: v2
      labels:
        version: "1.1"
```